# How to draw horizontal lines For (First candle) in year

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I am trying to draw horizontal lines on first candle in year , lines on high and low for candle .. For example, if the time frame is daily, we want to put two lines, higher and lower, on the first candle of the year, and on the weekly, we can specify the first weekly candle of the year, and so on. Can I help with this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UaW1.jpg)

```
//@version=5
indicator("OPOFHL", overlay=true)

is_new(resolution) =>
    t = time(resolution)
    not na(t) and (na(t[1]) or t > t[1])

is_new_year() => is_new('12M')

var float hi = na
var float lo = na

hi := is_new_year() ? high : hi
lo := is_new_year() ? low : lo

plot(hi, "High", color.green, 1, plot.style_circles)
plot(lo, "Low", color.red, 1, plot.style_circles)
```

Comment: Your code works fine. First candle of the year happens to be 4th of January in 2021 and 3rd of January in 2022. What's wrong with it?

Comment: welcome vitruvius ..
The attached picture is to clarify what I mean.. The attached code gives incorrect random results ..
https://freeimage.host/i/HniSziv

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I may not have succeeded in explaining the problem.

I need code:
- Reveals the first candle of the beginning of the Gregorian year
- Then I want to draw a horizontal line on high of the candle and another line on low of the candle

And thanks in advance

I attached a link to a picture of the chart.. it contains a description of the problem
https://h.top4top.io/p_25379zdvo1.png